# How to set a default value for Card in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am doing a project status dashboard that consists of few projects, and each project got a different project lead.
I have a card visualization which shows project lead when a user selects the certain project. 
My issue is when I open the dashboard, if I don't select any project, the card always shows the project lead of the first project. Is there anyway I can set a **customized** default value for the card before i select any project?

Thanks

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is `no, you can't set a default value`, **BUT** you can save a report with a chosen value for a slicer, and that value will show the same value when you open the report again. If you go to the [Power BI forum](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas?query=default%20slicer%20value), you will see that default values for slices has been suggested quite a few times

The last selected value for a `Slicer` will remain the same if you s`ave, close and restart` a pbix file. And as a consequence, so will the `Card` showing the project lead if the `Card` and `Slicer` are connected.

Here are some details:

---

**1.** Use `Enter Data` to insert a table with two columns Project and Lead, and insert three projects `A, B and C` with three project leads `Dan, Stan and Sam`:

[image]

**2.** Insert a `Multi-row Card` and both columns.

**3.** Insert a `Slicer` and assign 'Project' to get this setup:

[image]

**4.** Select `Project B` and make sure that the Multi-Row Card is subset correctly:

[image]

**5.** `Save, close and restart` and you should still be getting this:

[image]

Please let me know if this was not what you were looking for.

**Edit 1**

You can just as easily have a slicer with the project lead:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But this is not I am looking for. I will share some screenshot later on.

Comment: I might be misleading. I had attached a screenshot which might be easier to understand. Thanks~

Comment: You can just as easily have a slicer with the project lead. It *will* stay the same after saving, closing and reopening Power BI.

Comment: Can I set up a customized default value in slicer? in this case, I might set the default value as "The team", then if I select a certain project, it will still show the project lead accordingly? Sorry I missed out my keyword "Customized" in my question. :)

Comment: The answer is "no", you can't set a default value, "BUT" you can save a report with a chosen value for a slicer, and that value will show the same value when you open the report again. If you go to the [Power BI forum](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas?query=default%20slicer%20value), you will see that default values for slices has been suggested quite a few times

Comment: alright~guess i need to think out another way to present! Thank you ~

Comment: No problem! Sign up in the Power BI forum and VOTE =)